# Any note on Immersed boundary finite difference method?

Tags: matlab, finite-difference, reference-request, simulation

For parts of a talk, I need a note on "Immersed boundary finite difference method", mainly about the reason of appearing this branch in the finite difference methods, considering mathematical principles and algorithm of implementation related to it. A survey paper, chapter of a book, lecture note or any other material concerning this topic discussing the mathematics behind is very good. Also, I need a MATLAB simulation of this method.

Comment: Hi @MohammadKhosravi, and welcome to scicomp!  Do you mean [immersed interface method](http://journal.taiwanmathsoc.org.tw/index.php/TJM/article/view/1112)?

Comment: @Paul, Hi Paul. please check this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersed_boundary_method

Comment: A cursory google search yields [this paper](http://www.stanford.edu/group/uq/pdfs/journals/annurev_05.pdf), which gives a good overview of the method and its versatility as a computational tool.  As for matlab code, check out [this zip file](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~ehan/math6790/project1/)  Also, check out [Peskin's website](http://math.nyu.edu/faculty/peskin/ib_lecture_notes/)

Comment: @Paul I have seen this paper, but it doesn't have any theoretical and mathematical discussion. Besides, there is no strong discussion about FD.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information on what you are looking for.  The immersed boundary method is a method to simulate the motion of structures immersed in a fluid; in general, it involves coupling a fluid solver to the dynamics of some other structures.  This fluid solver may be implemented using finite difference, but I don't believe it has to be.  What do you mean specifically by "immersed boundary finite difference"?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following paper: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1748-3190/aa5e08/meta

It's our overview of Peskin's Immersed Boundary Method with open source (full) implementations in both MATLAB and Python 3, here:

https://github.com/nickabattista/IB2d